# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet with name

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, servlets

i am doing sample on spring webservices,when i run this sample i am getting below error

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringRestfulWebServicesExample/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springrest'

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
 <web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>  
  <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class>  
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  
</servlet-class>  
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

springrest-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">  
<mvc:annotation-driven/>  
<context:component-scan base-package="org.arpit.java2blog.controller" />  
</beans>
```

SpringrestfulwebserviceExample.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>  
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
 <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
 <version>3.1.0</version>  
 </dependency>  

  <dependency>  
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
   <version>${spring.version}</version>  
  </dependency>  
  <dependency>  
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
  <version>${spring.version}</version>  
   </dependency>  
   </dependencies>
   <build>

   <finalName>SpringRestfulWebServicesExample</finalName>

   <plugins>  
  <plugin>  
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
  <version>3.1</version>  
  <configuration>  
  <source>${jdk.version}</source>  
  <target>${jdk.version}</target>  
  </configuration>  
  </plugin>  
  </plugins>  
  </build>

  <properties>  
  <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>  
  <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>  
  </properties>

  </project>
```

Springrestcontroller.java

```
    @RestController  
    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public class SpringRestController {  
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public String hello(@PathVariable String name) {  
    String result="Hello "+name;    
    return result;  
   }  
   }
```

in springrest-servlet.xml i am getting below errors

```
1. cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'
2. Multiple annotations found at this line:
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document   'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd', because    1) could 
 not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root   element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'.
```

error

```
Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFO: Server built:          Dec 1 2015 22:30:46 UTC
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFO: Server number:         8.0.30.0
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: OS Version:            6.1
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
   INFO: Architecture:          amd64
   Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
   INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre
   Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
   INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_65-b17
   Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
   Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
   Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache  Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
     INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\wtpwebapps
   Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
   INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache    Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
  INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal   performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:     C:\Program   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Window   s;D:/supriya/bin/server;D:/supriya/bin;D:/supriya/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracl  e\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program    Files\Intel\iCLS  Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\Syste        m32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL     SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\android-sdk-  win\tools;C:\android-sdk-win\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Users\star\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Titanium   Studio;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files   (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform   Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web   Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\SourceGear\Common\DiffMerge\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\star\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\star\Desktop\eclipse-jee-mars-1-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
 INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool  getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1108 ms
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
 INFO: Starting service Catalina
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
 INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
 INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\Apache Software  Foundation\Tomcat  8.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\SpringRestfulWebServicesExample.xml
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
 WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:SpringRestfulWebServicesExample' did not find a matching property.
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:56 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
 INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable   debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but   no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve   startup time and JSP compilation time.
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:56 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
 INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [219] milliseconds.
Dec 27, 2015 11:11:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springrest'
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
 INFO: FrameworkServlet 'springrest': initialization started
Dec 27, 2015 11:11:56 PM     org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springrest-servlet': startup date [Sun Dec 27 23:11:56 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 27, 2015 11:11:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springrest-servlet.xml]
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
 INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springrest-servlet': startup date [Sun Dec 27 23:11:56 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapt er initControllerAdviceCache
 INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace   'springrest-servlet': startup date [Sun Dec 27 23:11:56 IST 2015]; root of   context hierarchy
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
 INFO: FrameworkServlet 'springrest': initialization completed in 1569 ms
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
 INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\Apache   Software Foundation\Tomcat   8.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\SpringRestfulWebServicesExample.xml has finished in   3,832 ms
 Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software  Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
  INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache   Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs has finished in 39 ms
   Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
   INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache   Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager
   Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
   INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache   Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager has finished in 55 ms
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
  INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
  INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT has finished in 31 ms
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
  INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
  Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
  INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
   Dec 27, 2015 11:11:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
  INFO: Server startup in 4031 ms
  Dec 27, 2015 11:12:46 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  noHandlerFound
  WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringRestfulWebServicesExample/hello/name] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springrest'
```

[image]

How to solve these issues.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What url you requested?

Comment: @Tom Sebastian http://localhost:8080/SpringRestfulWebServicesExample/hello/harry

Answer (score 0):

Change your `springrest` servlet url pattern to either of the following

**`<url-pattern>/SpringRestfulWebServicesExample/*</url-pattern>`**

or

**`<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`**

Since servlet url pattern with `/*` will match

```
 http://<ip>:<port>/*
```

not the path relative to your context name `SpringRestfulWebServicesExample`. For relative path try using pattern `/`.It will match for  `http://<ip>:<port>/SpringRestfulWebServicesExample/*`

**Update :**
The spring version configured in the pom.xml and the schema version used in the bean configuration files should be matching.
The schema provided in your configuration file is spring 3.0.x which will not be there in the classpath jars.For the xml error replace with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
  <context:component-scan base-package="org.arpit.java2blog.controller" />  
</beans>
```

Also add these dependencies to pom and try:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i am also getting error   cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'  in springrest-servlet.xml

Comment: After changing the pattern does the url work?

Comment: @allDroid see my update.It is a working copy

Comment: in xml it showing same error so i am not able to run on server

Comment: After making above changes can you trigger maven build and manually deploy generated war file in tomcat webapps and run to see is it a problem with eclipse

Comment: see updated post.i have showen console errors and project structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99059/discussion-between-alldroid-and-tom-sebastian).

Comment: Please see the updated dependencies along with the xml spring config

Comment: .the error remains same in xml file .if i run tomcat by  http://localhost:8080/SpringRestfulWebServicesExample/ i am getting hello world! but for http://localhost:8080/SpringRestfulWebServicesExample/hello/name i get The requested resource is not available.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your project structure you placed **java** files inside `src>main>resources`.

You need to place it `src>main>java`